# using talend to output data not matched in lookup table

Tags: talend, lookup-tables

I know how to use talend's tMap component to output matched data in lookup data, however, I don't know how to output these rows that is not matched with data in lookup table. Maybe a simple question to senior user. Thanks all the way.

Regards,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Two steps are required to gather rejected rows:

- On the left hand side you have to set `Join Model` to `Inner Join` on the join you want to find rejected rows

[image]

- On the right hand side set `Catch lookup inner join reject` to `true`. This row will get all rejected entries. So you can create one row which gets all found entries and another row which delivers only the rejected rows

[image]

Usually this leads to a *tMap* with two output rows in your job.

Answer (score 0):

in tMap output table there is setting options. Go to that and there you will see couple of options like "Catch lookup inner join reject" & "catch output reject" - you can set them to false/true based on your need. My guess is that you are looking for "Catch lookup inner join reject".